# Capacitor between grounds: Reason and how to decide the value

Tags: rf, noise, grounding, differential

[image: Reference image]

while going through the reference designs, I came across the capacitor between grounds. Is it for RF noise protection?
Is ground for U4 and other part of the circuit is different?

Comment: As drawn, that capacitor connects to the same GND on both sides. Ergo, it is **shorted** and **does nothing**. My guess is that perhaps they needed some shape on the PCB to solder a wire to or this is simply an **error**.

Comment: You removed from that schematic the part where it says those caps are not mounted... I think its basically a visual identification for different models, as you can see on the pcb that thing is soldered directly onto the gnd layer

Comment: I once did this as an experiment to eliminate an occasional glitch in an A/D converter. The converter called for analog GND and digital GND to be tied at one point at the converter. The system had them tied offboard back at the power-supply. The experiment worked, but the rework was not allowed as it was part of aviation equipment that had already undergone governmental testing.

Comment: @PlasmaHH This particular capacitor, c18, is connected on the main board. Others were not mounted, so I removed them from schematic.

Comment: @HarshSingh So how is it connected? Is there continuity between the two terminals?

Comment: @HarshSingh: if you don't know why something is in the schematic, leave it in. This is a crucial information, as it says that the others are not mounted. It says that becase -- as I mentioned already -- they are functioning as visual identification for the different models, as is hinted by the "_Differentiation" heading for that schematic section.

Comment: @Tut how did you tied those grounds together. Was it using capacitors?

Comment: @PlasmaHH probably you are right.. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Tut...In mixed signals in the same chip you can get uneven ground bounce.  I have seen conflicting suggestions on the best way to handle it and prevent ground loops and even possible latch-up.  What you did was one.  Another is tying the grounds together with anti-parallel schottky diodes.  Another is to tie the two grounds together at the chip and live with any ground loop.

Comment: @HarshSingh ... Yes a single capacitor between analog GND and digital GND which were tied together back at the power-supply.

Comment: For odd things like this, the schematic simply isn't useful. You'll have to check the layout. Same thing with random decoupling caps between Vdd and ground, that are placed at some random place in the schematic. You can't tell which IC they are supposed to decouple without checking the layout.

Answer (score 7):

Its a NL\switchable part that is used for identification only (almost definitely). It appears that they use a capacitor to indicate what kind of board it is visually. On other boards, if the grounds were different on either side I'd say it was a ground connection but the ground is the same so it serves no purpose electrically.
[image]

Comment: Ah the joys of components being dirt cheap in bulk.